# Correct way of specifying similar locations for nginx

Tags: webserver, nginx, reverse-proxy, web-hosting

I'm very new to hosting and nginx and fairly new to linux and just started to host a web-app on my raspberry pi (intranet only) using nginx.
It serves an angular SPA on `/`, redirects to a .NET API on `/api` and redirects to a signalR hub on `/realTimeFeed` (that basically means websockets if you don't know signalR).

Everything seems to work fine but as you're able to see below, there is a lot of redundancy between `/api` and `/realTimeFeed`.
**How can I change that? *Should* I even change that? Is this even remotely correct?**

My references are the following (admittedly, I copied my solution together from these links):

- https://github.com/diginex/nginx-spa/blob/master/default.conf (SPA)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-nginx (api)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1#linux-with-nginx (signalR / websockets)

Below is my configuration file for nginx at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/api;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /realTimeFeed {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/realTimeFeed;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

In order for signalR / websockets to work correctly, I also added this section to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# For SignalR
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default Upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
```

If this is off-topic and or belongs elsewhere, please let me know :)

EDIT:

I tried the following but that didn't work. Didn't work means the websocket connection wasn't proxied correctly and an error was thrown on the client-side saying the connection couldn't be established.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/api;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    }

    location /realTimeFeed {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/realTimeFeed;
        proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either move the common directives into the outer block so that they are inherited by each `location` or move them into a separate file and use an `include` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) and note the **Context** of each directive.

Comment: I think I can't put it in the server context because then it would also be applied to `location /` right? You mention splitting it into different files, is there a way of splitting it _within_ the file?

Comment: Proxy directives only affect locations with a `proxy_pass`

Comment: Awesome, that'll do. I'll self-answer once/if I figure out how to do it. As a side question, do you happen to know if it's okay to put this mapping for SignalR in `nginx.conf` or should that go elsewhere? In the guide I linked it's in the html context and I can't put a second html context in the `default` file so I just put it there.

Comment: @RichardSmith unfortunately I didn't manage to get it to work with that :/ you can check my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I even change that?

If it is working correctly, I would say no.

> Is this even remotely correct?

[Options other than `proxy_pass` are not technically required to proxy basic requests](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/). However, if you wish, you can try removing additional directives individually (per `location`) until something breaks. ;)

More seriously, the additional directives you have specified may be desirable/necessary for other reasons (including allowing your applications to function correctly behind a proxy). If Microsoft has recommended those settings, then there is likely some thought behind that.

> Everything seems to work fine but as you're able to see below, there is a lot of redundancy between `/api` and `/realTimeFeed`. How can I change that?

You may with to try using `include` directives to include your common proxy settings e.g.:

*ex. common_proxy_settings.conf*

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

*ex. "included" server block*

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;

    location /api {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/api;
        include /path/to/common_proxy_settings.conf
    }

    location /realTimeFeed {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000/realTimeFeed;
        include /path/to/common_proxy_settings.conf
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html; # redirect all request to index.html
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```